# How do I compare rows of a table against all other rows of the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to create a script that takes the rows of a table which have a specific mathematical difference in their ASCII sum and to add the rows to a separate table, or even to flag a different field when they have that difference.

For instance, I am looking to find when the ASCII sum of word A and the ASCII sum of word B, both stored in rows of a table, have a difference of 63 or 31.

I could probably use a loop to select these rows, but SQL is not my greatest virtue.

```
ItemID | asciiSum |ProperDiff
-------|----------|----------
1      | 100      |
2      | 37       |
3      | 69       |
4      | 23       |
5      | 6        |
6      | 38       |
```

After running the code, the field ProperDiff will be updated to contain 'yes' for ItemID 1,2,3,5,6, since the AsciiSum for 1 and 2 (100-37) = 63 etc.

Comment: Post sample data and expected result..

Comment: You say items 1,2,3,5 and 6 should be 'yes', but the diff should be 32, not 31, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not be fast, but I think it does what you want:

```
update t
    set ProperDiff = 'yes'
    where exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where abs(t2.AsciiSum - t.AsciiSum) in (63, 31)
                 );
```

It should work okay on small tables.